# Oauth2 Header - "Authorization: Bearer (token)" doesn't work

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen, bearer-token

I am using Lumen as backend. I successfully authenticated user and got the token, but when I am trying to get protected data, it doesn't let me with `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN`. I tried with both Postman & Swift. ( I also tried `Authorization: BearerTOKEN` )

I tried making a call from ios app and adding header: `Authorization: Bearer y57WWNRNKNpJkXugT6v1YG7Et13PBgT5xNkAB1bg` however it doesn't let me pass the validation. Specifically:

```
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
```

Then I tried in postman: GET, set headers:

- `Authorization` `Bearer y57WWNRNKNpJkXugT6v1YG7Et13PBgT5xNkAB1bg`

Still no luck. I am getting

> error = "access_denied";
>
> "error_description" = "The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.";

P.S: `/me?access_token = 84389...` works fine

Comment: If you are using apache, add this to your `.htaccess` RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

Comment: @Digitlimit I don't have `.htaccess` anywhere :/ Where is it located?

Comment: are you using apache? if yes, create one

Comment: If you are using vagrant means nginx and not apache server hence no need for the .htacccess, I suggest you try using POSTMAN to test, another way is to pass the token directly in the URL like so: http://devsite.dev/api/v1/protected?token=y57WWNRNKNpJkXugT6v1YG7Et13PBgT5xNkAB1bg

Comment: I tried replacing the code at the top of `.htaccess` with your suggestion, but still it doesn't pass Postman neither with `/me?Authorization=Bearer y57WW` nor `/me?Authorization=Bearery57WW`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96768/discussion-between-senty-and-digitlimit).