# Can apache prevent bearer authentication header?

Tags: apache, lumen

I am testing lumen 5.3 with a deprecated oauth2 project. There is a tutorial using proxy and hiding client ID and secret on the server .

Lumen does not has passport ported so I have to use this package.

Anyway. I managed to go far enough to get the token from server.

But my Authentication header has been ignored by Lumen.

Where is the Authentication header? I send it for sure.

So I wonder now , is it apache ? Some module is needed? For this Bearer Authentication?

Answer (score 3):

**Apache2 "by default" does this!!!**

Add this into your .htaccess to solve this.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*) 
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

See:

[Oauth2 Header - "Authorization: Bearer (token)" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036781/oauth2-header-authorization-bearer-token-doesnt-work)

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/262